# Solving probability question using contingency tables involving use of set intersection

Tags: probability

I am having a great deal of difficulty understanding a part of this topic. The question I am provided with contains a contingency table and asked to find the probability of A and B occurring. Online and in my notes show that you simply look where the rows and columns intersect and that value over the total amount is the probability of the both events occurring. This makes sense to me however the source of my confusion is that there is a rule that states, for independent events, that that $P( A \cap B)=P(A )*P(B)$.  But why is the value of $P(A )*P(B)$ not equal to the probability of the intersection value found on the table? Am I missing a rule?

Comment: Are you sure $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be independent events?

Comment: @AlexKruckman should I upload the exact table so you can better see what I mean?